# Autodesk Forge: Issue, SolidWorks files with derived configurations

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, solidworks, autodesk-model-derivative

## Autodesk Forge

### Translating SolidWorks files with derived configurations

#### Issue

When translating solidworks assemblies that contains parts with derived configurations, 
`parts suppressed` in the derived configuration will `still appear`.

Below is 2 pictures, one showing the view in solidworks and the other showing a snapshot from the Forge Viewer.

We have tried rebuilding the assembly and all parts included multiple times but are still facing the same issues.

#### Question

First of all, is derived configurations supported by the translation service?

Anyone with advice on how this issue can be mitigated?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This sounds to be a bug in our Solidworks extractor. I'll report the issue to get it fixed. As workaround, I would suggest you take a look to these items properties and check if there is any telling you they are derived components. If you can identify them, just hide them when loading. Let me know if you need help in writing the code.

Comment: Thank you Cyrille.  Let me know if there is anything I can do to support further!
I did look thru the properties again, and I can't find anything to filter out the components. However, I noticed that the Assembly with the derived configuration does not have a an active configuration property, which all other parts/assemblies with configurations has.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with translation service, but obvious workaround with Solidworks API would be to delete all suppressed components before translation. Let me know if you need me to point you towards API methods that you'll need.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with the Solidworks API and how Solidworks handles files internally. We are using the same assembly/file and it's different configurations in multiple places in the complete assembly. I guess this would be a problem when deleting the suppressed components? If the components are used elsewhere in the complete model?

Comment: Component is just a reference to the actual part. You should have no issues deleting suppressed components. The thing is if you do need them suppressed and not removed you'll need to make a backup, delete them, translate the document and then restore your backup.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check the result when you import same model into Inventor.

Comment: Hello Karl, another suggestion is to export the assembly from SolidWorks to STEP and load the STEP into any STEP viewer (Inventor or Forge). If the STEP is correct, we will need your dataset if you can share your files with Autodesk.